# Java delimiter pattern for whitespace & punctuation?

Tags: java, parsing, pattern-matching, java.util.scanner

What is the expression for a scanner delimiter pattern for using whitespace and punctuation without including the `\n`? I need mine to read a paragraph in a txt file and be able to ignore spaces and punctuation, but keep track of the line number

Answer (score 0):

Well just a simple group of all of them:

```
pattern = "[ \\t\\.,:;\\r]"
```

Comment: So when I printed every word out in different line, the newline space is giving me a blank line. When I use `if(str.equals("\n"));` the line number isn't incrementing.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you. But if I do add \r to the pattern.